# Fazer Cálculos no Banco Sql Server

Tags: sql

Estou fazendo uma aplicação com banco de dados SQl Server e quero que o banco trabalhe os cálculos e não a aplicação, mas estou com dificuldades pra fazer, espero que alguém possa me ajudar nessa questão.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estas são as colunas da tabela Produto, os dados foram inserido manualmente, as colunas TotalCompra e TotalVenda são computadas (Estoque * ValorCompra) e (Estoque * Valorvenda), respectivamente. Agora é que vem a dificuldade, quero que o valor na coluna Lucro também seja automático sendo (TotalVenda -TotalCompra)

Fiz a seguinte Procedure de Inserir:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, o que você quer?

Comment: Quero calcular valor na coluna Lucro também de forma automática sendo (TotalVenda -TotalCompra). Que o calculo seja feito na tabela. E não na aplicação.

Comment: Não seria só criar mais uma coluna calculada !?

Comment: Não Motta, porque as colunas TotalCompra e TotalVenda já são Colunas Calculadas, já tentei assim e não deu certo.

Comment: Não é só fazer uma coluna calculada da seguinte forma: `Lucro = (ValorVenda - ValorCompra) * Estoque`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE Produto
ADD Lucro AS ((ValorVenda - ValorCompra) * Estoque);
```

Comment: Valeu Marcelo Uchimura, deu certo!

Answer (score -1):

Não entendi muito bem o que você quer, mas você pode usar o SUM para exibir essa informação sempre que precisar, sem precisar armazenar o total.

```
SELECT Sum(VALOR_COMPRA - VALOR_VENDA) FROM ... ;
```

Ou pode inserir de forma simples e rápida, assim como neste exemplo:

```
INSERT INTO TESTE (valorcompra, valorvenda, lucro) VALUES (155,195, valorvenda - valorcompra)
```

creio que possa também usar dentro do procedure!

```
values {
...
...
@VALOR_COMPRA, 
@VALOR_VENDA,
Lucro = @VALOR_COMPRA - @VALOR_VENDA

}
```

Comment: Marcos Vinicius é quase isso, mas quero calcular esse diferença entre os TotalCompra e Totalvenda que não estão na procedure, essas informações só se encontram na tabela.

Comment: Já tentou isso? Sem passar as duas colunas que quer por parâmetros  Lucro = TOTAL_COMPRA - TOTAL_VENDA